# glCompileShader Crashes on OSX

Tags: c, macos, opengl

This has got me stumped. I am writing an OpenGL application on my Macbook Pro running OSX Yosemite using Objective C / C. My application always crashes on `glCompileShader(...)` and I was hoping one of you could help me find out why.

All other GL3+ functions work perfectly and produce no error messages or flags. In addition, I have tried using GLEW to see if that would fix the problem but it has not. I would put this down to being a simple driver bug if not for the fact I have written tons of OpenGL application on this Macbook and have never encountered this problem before.

Here is the code I am using to load and compile the vertex shader:

```
shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
const GLchar *v = vertSrc;

shaderVertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(shaderVertex, 1, &v, NULL);
glCompileShader(shaderVertex); // This is where it crashes
```

Here is the vertex shader source itself:

```
const char *vertSrc = {
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec3 vPosition;\n"
"in vec3 vRotation;\n"
"in vec4 vColor;\n"
"in vec3 vNormal;\n"
"in vec3 vTexture;\n"
"uniform mat4 mModel;\n"
"uniform mat4 mView;\n"
"uniform mat4 mProj;\n"
"void main(){\n"
    "gl_Position = (mProj * mView * mModel) * vec4(vPosition.xyz,1.0);\n"
"}\n"
};
```

Finally, here is the Problem Report generated by Apple when the application crashes:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff00000000

VM Regions Near 0x7fff00000000:
    MALLOC_SMALL           00007fbc64000000-00007fbc65000000 [ 16.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    STACK GUARD            00007fff59b6c000-00007fff5d36c000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff895d1c43 __findenv + 90
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff895d1cc7 getenv + 29
2   libGLProgrammability.dylib      0x00007fff894a504a glpMakeCompiler + 266
3   libGLProgrammability.dylib      0x00007fff894cf9ca ShCompile + 124
4   GLEngine                        0x00007fff9351e3bb gleShaderParse + 482
5   GLEngine                        0x00007fff93464f36 glCompileShaderIncludeARB_Exec + 490
6   libCarbon.dylib                 0x000000010209dd97 myApp_addShaderProgram + 231
7   libCarbon.dylib                 0x000000010209dc2f myApp_setShaderGroup + 63
8   main                            0x0000000102095b8a main + 458
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff965fa5c9 start + 1
```

Has anybody seen this error before or believe they can help?

Comment: If you create a minimal application that does nothing except try to compile that same shader, does it still crash? If it crashes standalone, I would file a bug with Apple and try to rewrite your shader so it doesn't cause the crash. Otherwise: I ask because it seems odd that it crashes in `getenv()` - this doesn't seem like it would be data dependent, so it's more likely that you've got yourself an accidental memory overwrite somewhere in your app. Have you run the full gamut of memory checks? Can you test your application in `valgrind`?

Comment: It could be an unrelated memory splat somewhere else in your code that happens to break at this point. Try enabling the memory debug features to see if it flags anything: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001884-CJBJFIDD